Not able to install Enterprise CA on Active Directory
I am trying to install an Enterprise CA on my Active Directory.
However when I am in the setup, I am not able to select Enterprise CA, does anyone know how to solve this?
I have admin rights on my user.
Screenshot of the installation step where I have to select Enterprise CA.
Update: Thanks for the help. Adding my user to the Enterprise Admin group and restarting the server worked for me.

You need Enterprise Admins rights in order to install Enterprise CA and server must be joined to AD.
